# Replacing every nth line in one file with next line from another file in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, replace, while-loop

I'm very new to this, and realize that there are similar questions already posted, but I can't quite figure out what I need from them. I have two files.

File 1:

```
1: Read 1
2: Sequence 1
3: +
4: Quality 1
5: Read 2
6: Sequence 2 
7: +
8: Quality 2
...
```

File 2:

```
1: Sequence 1 edited
2: Sequence 2 edited
3: Sequence 3 edited
4: Sequence 4 edited
...
```

Starting with line 2 of the first file, I need to replace every 4th line with the next read line in the second file, so the outcome would look like this:

```
1: Read 1
2: Sequence 1 edited
3: +
4: Quality 1
5: Read 2
6: Sequence 2 edited 
7: +
8: Quality 2
...
```

So far, I've been using this code, which seems to work, but is slow as a command and painfully so as a shell script:

```
Counter=2
while read p; do echo $Counter; echo $p; 
    sed -i~ "${Counter}s/^.*/$p/" file 1; 
    Counter=$((Counter+4)); done < file 2
```

I think I should be able to do it using awk, but I'm not sure how. Any help or improvements would be appreciated!

Comment: Please break the one-liner into multiple lines for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the line numbers are just for explanation purpose and *not* included in the files, please try the following:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {line[NR]=$0; next} {if (FNR%4==2) $0=line[++count]; print}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
Read 1
Sequence 1 edited
+
Quality 1
Read 2
Sequence 2 edited
+
Quality 2
...
```

[Explanations]

- The condition `NR==FNR` matches only when reading `file2` and it stores
  the lines in the array `line` in order.
- The following `{if ...` statement is executed only when reading `file1`.
  If the line number of file1 is equal to 2 with modulus of 4, the line
  is replaced by the content of the array `line`.

Comment: Your assumption was correct- sorry for the lack of clarity. This seems to do the trick, and much more quickly! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Good to know it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using awk and paste

```
awk ' { print "\n" $0 "\n" "\n" } ' file2.txt | 
     paste - file1.txt | awk -F"\t" ' {x=NR%4==2 ? $1 : $2; print x } '
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat cmswen1.txt
Read 1
Sequence 1
+
Quality 1
Read 2
Sequence 2
+
Quality 2

$ cat cmswen2.txt
Sequence 1 edited
Sequence 2 edited
Sequence 3 edited
Sequence 4 edited

$ awk ' { print "\n" $0 "\n" "\n" } ' cmswen2.txt | 
     paste - cmswen1.txt | awk -F"\t" ' {x=NR%4==2 ? $1 : $2; print x } '
Read 1
Sequence 1 edited
+
Quality 1
Read 2
Sequence 2 edited
+
Quality 2

Sequence 3 edited



Sequence 4 edited



$
```